# How to obtain the output result of gpg --edit-key in bash script?

Tags: bash, gnupg

What about getting the output of

```
echo -e "quit\n" | gpg --command-fd 0 --edit-key userid
```

in a bash script?
Try outputting the result to variable var:

```
var=$(echo -e "quit\n" | gpg --command-fd 0 --edit-key userid)
echo "$var"
```

I don't get the expected result.
Try to output the result to file file:

```
echo -e "quit\n" | gpg --command-fd 0 --edit-key userid | tee file
cat file
```

same failure.
Why not ok and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var=$(echo -e "quit\n" | gpg --command-fd 0 --edit-key userid 2>&1 > /dev/null)
echo "$var"
```

It works on me.